# Tiempos de carga de chrome con selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scraping

Estoy haciendo un web scraping con selenium webdriver en python, mi problema es que necesito cargar mas de 500 paginas y me tarda en total mas de 2 horas por la acumulacion de tiempo al cargar tantas paginas. Hay alguna forma de reducir los tiempos de carga de una pagina en Chrome?. Me recomendais otro buscador o Chrome esta bien?

Comment: Lo que te recomiendo es hacer un poco de multithreading, es muy común para hacer scraping en múltiples páginas, y suele ayudar mucho a rebajar los tiempos.

Comment: Puedes filtrar imágenes y archivos pesados así solo obtienes el texto.